# Help in updating multiple person field via powershell - Only updates one user

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

Im trying to update multiple person field but it only updates one person not multiple users.ONLY THE LAST ONE

As you can see below i'm picking up display name from a field "Contract Viewer" which has values like so: "abc,def,ghi"

Sure i'm missing something.
Thanks in Advance

See code below:

```
function Update([string] $itemid)
   {
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection] $ReviewersList = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection
   $CMRSItems = $list.Items | where  {$_['ID'] -eq $itemid}
   $CMRSItems | ForEach-Object {

   #my real values are like this "abc,def,ghi"

   $realval =  $_['Contract Viewer']
   #$split = $realval.Split(";#").Trim()

    $array = @($realval.Split(','))
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Count - 1; $i++)
        {
            $number = $array[$i]

            $user = getSPuser -webURL $webURL -displayname $number
            #Check if user exists
            if($user -ne $null)
            {
            #Get list from Ensurer
            $userlist = GetReviewLists -user $user
            Write-Host $userlist
            #add userslist
            $ReviewersList.Add($userlist)
            }           

        }

         Write-Host $ReviewersList
         #Not sure its aoonly updating the last one
         $CMRSItems["Contract Viewer1"] = $ReviewersList;            
         $CMRSItems.Update();
         $web.Dispose();

    }       

}


 function getSPuser([string] $webURL,[string] $displayname)
{
    $user=Get-SPUser –web $webURL | where{$_.displayname -contains $displayname}
    $email = $user.email
    return $email
}

function GetAllItems()
   {
    #this loops through items from 1 to 2 for example
    $CMRSItems = $list.Items | where  {($_['ID'] -gt 0) -and ($_['ID'] -le 2)}
    $CMRSItems | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "RefID: " $_['RefID']
    Write-Host "ItemID: " $_['ID']
    Update -itemid $_['ID']
    }
}


function GetReviewLists([string] $userlist)
    {

    $spUser = $web.EnsureUser($userlist)
    $ReviewerValue = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($web, $spUser.ID, $spUser.LoginName)
    return $ReviewerValue              


    }
GetAllItems
```

`

Comment: Try $CMRSItems.Fields["Contract Viewer1"].ParseAndSetValue($CMRSItems,$ReviewersList);            
$CMRSItems.Update();

Comment: your for loop is not doing it correctly.it will just iterate with 2 items. its like for(I=0,i<2;i++). so 3rd item will never go through the loop. so it is directly taking the one item because your for loop never executes properly

Comment: My script was good.the column wasnt setup to have multiple values.Thanks Guys